# Cargar automáticamente estilo usando HTML, JavaScript y CSS

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una vista para login la cual al colocar el mouse realiza una acción, el problema que tengo es que al colocar el mouse por primera vez luego de refrescar la pagina, las letras en este caso PROFESOR se ve con fondo blanco y en unos segundos mas cambia a azul, quiero que cargue automáticamente con el fondo azul, adjunto fotos del problema y mi código.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('ul.thumb li').Zoomer({
    speedView: 500,
    speedRemove: 400,
    altAnim: true,
    speedTitle: 400,
    debug: false
  });
});
```

```css
h1 {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 6%;
  color: #D79B11;
}

ul.thumb {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 480px;
}

ul.thumb li {
  margin: 60px;
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
}

ul.thumb li img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}

ul.thumb li img.hover {
  margin-top: 15px;
  background: url() no-repeat center center;
  border: none;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  width: 185px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: url(img/blue.png) no-repeat center center;
  padding: 17px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>San Juan Bautista | Consulta de Datos</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <link href="estilo/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="images/favicon.ico" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Smooth-Image-Enlargement-Plugin-Zoomer/jquery.fs.zoomer.css"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Consulta de Datos</h1>
  <ul class="thumb">

    <li>
      <a href=""><img src="img/estudiante.png" alt="ALUMNO" /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="{{url('profesores/login')}}"><img src="img/docente.png" alt="PROFESOR" /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href=""><img src="img/administrativo.png" alt="ADMINISTRATIVO" /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="{{url('apoderados/login')}}"><img src="img/apoderado.png" alt="APODERADO" /></a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: login]

[image: login2]

Comment: que version de zoomer usas?

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a añadir esto en el head

```
<head><div id="loadOverlay" style="background-color:#333; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:2000;"></div>
```

Y al final de tu css esto

```
#loadOverlay{display: none;}
```

Esta es una forma facil de obligar a cargar los css antes de poder ver el html

Comment: se me ve la pantalla en negro

Comment: Entonces el motivo sigue siendo el css cuanto te demora la carga del css sin el div en el head?

Comment: Te falta esto dentro de la etiqueta style del head `#loadOverlay{display: none;}` no en el final del documento html

Answer (score 1):

bajale el tiempo al speedTitle, ajustalo en 100

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery('ul.thumb li').Zoomer({speedView:500,speedRemove:400,altAnim:true,speedTitle:400,debug:false});});
```